# Node / Express & Postgresql - when no rows match

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

Hello I am new to Postgresql and I wanted to learn how one handles 0 results as an error is thrown. Essentially I want to get a user if it doesn't exist, return null if one doesn't, and have an error handler. Below is the current code I am using. Any tips on a better way to do this are appreciated!

```
var options = {
  // Initialization Options
  promiseLib: promise
};
var pgp = require('pg-promise')(options);
var connectionString = 'postgres://localhost:5432/myDbName';
var db = pgp(connectionString);

function getUser(id) {         
  let user = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    try {
      db.one('select * from users where loginName = $1', id).then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        resolve(data); 
      }).catch (function (e) {
        console.log('error: '+e);
        reject(e);
      });
    }
    catch (e) {
      console.log('error: '+e);
      reject(e);
    }
  });
  return user;
}
```

output in console:

```
error: QueryResultError {
    code: queryResultErrorCode.noData
    message: "No data returned from the query."
    received: 0
    query: "select * from users where loginName = 'someUserName'"
}
```

Comment: which node postgres module are you using?

Comment: pg-promise (added to post in the most recent edit)

Comment: If not finding the row is a normal situation (not an error), you should use method `oneOrNone` instead, and check the resolved value for `null`. Use `.catch` for handling actual errors.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am the author of [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise).

---

In the realm of promises one uses `.then` to handle all normal situations and `.catch` to handle all error situations.

Translated into [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), which adheres to that rule, you execute a database method that resolves with results that represent all the normal situations, so anything else ends up in `.catch`.

Case in point, if returning one or no rows is a normal situation for your query, you should be using method [oneOrNone](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#.oneOrNone). It is only when returning no row is an invalid situation you would use method [one](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#.one).

As per the API, method [oneOrNone](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#.oneOrNone) resolves with the data row found, or with `null` when no row found, which you can check then:

```
db.oneOrNone('select * from users where loginName = $1', id)
    .then(user=> {
        if (user) {
            // user found
        } else {
            // user not found
        }
    })
    .catch(error=> {
        // something went wrong;     
    });
```

If, however, you have a query for which returning no data does represent an error, the proper way of checking for returning no rows would be like this:

```
var QRE = pgp.errors.QueryResultError;
var qrec = pgp.errors.queryResultErrorCode;

db.one('select * from users where loginName = $1', id)
    .then(user=> {
        // normal situation;
    })
    .catch(error=> {
        if (error instanceof QRE && error.code === qrec.noData) {
            // found no row
        } else {
            // something else is wrong;
        }
    });
```

Similar considerations are made when choosing method [many](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#.many) vs [manyOrNone](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#.manyOrNone) (method [any](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#.any) is a shorter alias for [manyOrNone](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#.manyOrNone)).

Type [QueryResultError](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/errors.QueryResultError.html) has a very friendly console output, just like all other types in the library, to give you a good idea of how to handle the situation.

Comment: Feel a bit honored the author of pg-promise answered the question. Thanks Vitaly-t !

Answer (score 1):

In your catch handler for the query, just test for that error. Looking at `pg-promise` source code, a code of noData is 0.  So just do something like this:

```
db.one('select * from users where loginName = $1', id).then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        resolve(data); 
      }).catch (function (e) {
        if(e.code === 0){
          resolve(null);
        }
        console.log('error: '+e);
        reject(e);
      });
```